# echo text of html file after submit a password

Tags: php, html, file, passwords

I have to do a php website for college.

I have to create a password and a submit button. After the I have posted the password I should get text from a html file. What is the best to achieve that?

I tried:

```
    foreach($files as $file2) {
if($_POST['submitPassword']){
if($file2 === '.' OR $file2 === '..' OR $file2 === 'thumbs.db' OR !is_dir($folder.'/'.$file2)) {continue;}
    if(file_exists($folder.'/'.$file2.'/doubleindemnity.gif') AND file_exists($folder.'/'.$file2.'/DOUBLEINDEMNITY.htm')) {
        echo '<div class="Container">';
        echo "<div class='image2'><img src='$folder/$file/doubleindemnity.gif'>";
        $lines4 = file($folder.'/'.$file2.'/DOUBLEINDEMNITY.htm');
         $count = count($lines4);
        for($a = 0;$a < $count;$a++) {
        echo substr($lines4[$a],strlen($folder),strpos($lines4[$a], '.')-strlen($folder));
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
      echo "</div>";
}
}
?>
```

Help would be highly appreciated:)

Cheers:)

Comment: So whats wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Asking for help passing a course? Anyhow, you're doing far too much and making this way to complicated. First your post should check the password is correct instead of just there. `$_POST['submitPassword'] == 'somePoorlyHardCodedPassword'` Next,  the loop should happen after you check the password, why check the password multiple time. Also, you don't have to scan all those and check for stuff existing, ($folder isn't even defined) just see if the file you want is there with `file_exists` and spit out the contents with `include()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Actually I ask for help in order to improve and to learn. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily include the contents of an html file through `include()`. For example:

```
include($folder.'/'.$file2.'/DOUBLEINDEMNITY.htm');
```

It will call the entire file, and output it (since it's not a PHP file for execution)